# How to slice a multidimensional array with a list of arrays of variable lengths vectorizing in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, vectorization, numpy-ndarray

**Data:** `x` is a n-dimensional array that gives the relative positions in 2 dimensions between pairs of particles in function of time. It has a shape of `(100, 50, 50, 2)`, where the axis correspond to time (100 frames), i particles (50 particles), j particles (50 particles) and the positions (2 coordinates). Additionally, I have two lists of arrays `iParticles` and `jParticles` that represent the *variable set of particles I want to consider in each time*: the length of the lists correspond to time (100 frames) and each element in the list is an array of integers representing a set of particles (they do not have a fixed length, they can vary from zero up to the total number of particles 50). For example:

```py
  import numpy as np

  x = np.random.rand(100, 50, 50, 2)

  #List of arrays of variable lengths
  iParticles = [np.random.randint(0, 50, size=np.random.randint(50)) for t in range(100)]  
  jParticles = [np.random.randint(0, 50, size=np.random.randint(50)) for t in range(100)]
```

**Problem:** I want to get the flattened array of the positions of `x` of the subset corresponding to the pairs of particles `iParticles` and `jParticles` for each time *vectorizing*. I would like to do something like:
`xSubSet_0 = x[:, iParticles, jParticles, 0].flatten()`, but this does not work.

- *Without vectorizing* I could achieve it with:

  ```py
  xSubSet_0 = []
  for t in range(100):
    for i in iParticles[t]:
      for j in jParticles[t]:
         xSubSet_0.append(x[t, i, j, 0])
  ```
- A *half-step in vectorizing* this problem without the time axis would be:

  ```py
  xSubSet_0 = np.concatenate([x[ t, iParticles[t][:, np.newaxis], jParticles[t], 0].flatten() for t in range(100)])
  ```

**Is it possible to fully vectorize the problem?**

Comment: Could you please add a clear example of your ideal output?

Comment: When declared those variables are empty lists, and it is much less likely that people will help you if they need to run your code in order to find out what output you are trying to achieve. I still think a clear example of the desired output would be best.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how to explain it better. I want to achieve the subset of `x` by the `iParticles` and `jParticles`: on the first coordinate, this would be represented by `x[:, iParticles, jParticles, 0]`. Because this subset does not have a fixed length on each dimension I would like to get the flattened version.

Comment: Maybe I do not understand correctly the problem, but how this code could be vectorized since you have to generate all the possible combinations between each pair of the `iparticles` and `jParticles` sub array ?

Comment: @obchardon I do not know a lot of Python, maybe it is not possible to vectorize this problem... I wonder then if there is another way to approach the problem (for example with the data expressed differently) in order to be able to vectorize it.

Comment: I can be wrong, but since the length of the sub array are not constant, IMO there is no way to fully vectorized this piece of code.

Comment: "vectorize" in the fast `numpy` sense means using `numpy` methods to perform the action in compiled methods.  Most of those work with whole mulltidimensional arrays.  "variable length" is a strong indicator that some sort of slow Python iteration will be required.  I suspect that the iteration on `t` will be required at some level.  After all you used it to generate the indices. :)